# Ionic Sidemenu with Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am looking for a solution where I need to have Ionic sidemenu and the main page should have Google map with current location.

Can someone please let me know how this can be achieved?

**UPDATED**

I have found something similar on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/yafraorg/pen/jBEky) and have tried to adopt the same to achieve my requirement. But still facing some issue.

My codepen link is http://codepen.io/guruprasadvenkatarao/pen/zGdYNr

I think the problem is somewhere in this code

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

.....

}
```

This function is never executed.

Can someone point what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should take a look at Ionic Getting Started http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/. There is a template with sidemenu. Also, you could look for some AngularJS directive for Google Maps like this one http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I assume you are probably a angular/ionic newbie like me. The reason, as you already figured out, is that the `addDomListener` is never triggered, so if you want the map to be initialized when you fire the view, instead of doing

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
    // ....
}
```

just do

```
$scope.initMap = function() {
    // your code here
}
```

and add the function to your map div like so:

```
<ion-view view-title="Map View">
    <ion-content>
        <div id="map" data-tap-disabled="true" ng-init="initMap()"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

---

p.s. after looking at your code, the first problem you need to fix is the google api key. If you look at line 24, you'll see

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<Google API key>=true"></script>
```

and you need to replace that with a valid key. Check out [Obtaining an API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key).

Let me know if you still have problems!